# Seeking PostGIS query to find LineStrings (Route) entering or crossing circle area?

Tags: postgis, linestring, circle

I need to know Postgis query to find LineStrings (Route) entering or crossing circle area. I tried using ST_Crosses function but it is not resulting with correct output.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share the query you used to help accurately diagnose the problem?

Comment: if `ST_Crosses` (and @Cushen's answer) doesnt't fit your needs, be more specific about why not and what kind of spatial relation you are after *exactly*.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **ST_Crosses**, **ST_Intersects** or many other such spatial queries.

This should work for what you want:
(change *'geom*' to match whatever it is in your tables)

```
SELECT r.* 
FROM route_table r, circle_table c    
WHERE ST_Crosses(r.geom, c.geom);
```